# Get commits of an item in one branch with TFS REST API

Tags: git, rest, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015

I am trying to get the history for one particular item in one particular branch in my git repository, using the Team Service REST API (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits).

I have this structure in my repository.

`Repository1
  -- Branch1 
       -- Item1
       -- Item2
  -- Branch2
       -- Item1
       -- Item3`

How can I get the commits for just Item1 in Branch1?

I have tried to POST: https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/commitsBatch?api-version=1.0

with JSON:

`{
   "itemVersion": {
     "versionType": "branch",
     "version": "Branch1"
   }
}`

But this gives me the commits for the whole branch.  How can I get the commits for just that item in that particular branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any direct way to get this with Rest API for now, you can submit a feature request on [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).

The alternative way to achieve this would be get all the commits in specified branch and get all the commits for specified item, and then list the commits exist in both scenarios.

Comment: Feel free to vote if you want to: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/14807604-git-rest-api-possibility-to-get-commits-for-one-p

Answer (score 2):

It is actually possible to do it exactly with commitsBatch. You don't have to get all branches and all commits and compare...

You do a POST to

https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/git/repositories/278d5cd2-584d-4b63-824a-2ba458937249/commitsBatch?api-version=1.0

and the JSON String is:

```
 {
   "itemPath":
     "/Folder1/Folder2/item1.extention",
   "$top":250
   "itemVersion": {
     "versionType": "branch",
     "version": "Branch1"
   }
}
```