# How can I programmatically link a commit to a work item in TFS? (need second GUID in LinkedArtifactURI)

Tags: c#, git, tfs, git-commit, tfs-workitem

I am attempting to programmatically link a commit to a work item in TFS and I think I'm close. When creating a new [ExternalLink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.externallink(v=vs.120).aspx), I'm struggling to form the `LinkedArtifactUri` property. I can run a simple query for a work item to see this property should like something like the following:

`"vstfs:///Git/Commit/ef43137b-a906-47b1-8dd4-0438b26c20c4%2fd211ee62-075d-4419-9d0b-cb58b76ae9dd%2fedfe1d438a77c2a95afa30e625f5dabe2656dea0"`

So I set out to determine where the GUIDs in this string come from and I was able to figure out the first two, but am currently stumped on the last one. The first GUID is the project ID (retrievable by doing something like `_store.Value.Projects[TEAM_NAME].guid`. The second is the Git Repo ID. Can someone please inform me as to what the third GUID might be?

Here is my code that should work if I can figure out where to get that last GUID:

```
var item = _store.Value.GetWorkItem(165464); //work item id #
var gitRepoService = _projectCollection.GetService<GitRepositoryService>();
var gitProjectRepoService = gitRepoService.QueryRepositories("TEAM_NAME");
var defaultGitRepo = gitProjectRepoService.Single(gr => 
gr.Name.Equals("REPO_NAME"));

var gitGuid = defaultGitRepo.Id;

var proj = _store.Value.Projects["TEAM_NAME"];
var id = proj.Guid;

var linkToAdd = new ExternalLink(_store.Value.RegisteredLinkTypes[ArtifactLinkIds.Commit], $"vstfs:///Git/Commit/{id}%{gitGuid}%{Where_does_this_guid_come_from}");
item.Links.Add(linkToAdd);
item.Save();
```

Thank you very much for your time. Please let me know if I am being unclear or if you need anything else from me.

Comment: Do you solve the issue with Andy's solution?

Comment: @starain-MSFT I was able to link the commit by hardcoding the commit ID and will now try to retrieve it from the REST API as he mentioned below. I will accept his answer after and reach out to you both if I have any issues. Thank you very much.

Comment: @starain-MSFT I'm not sure if you will get a notification for my response to Andy below but please check the comment and offer feedback if you have any. I'm having an issue selecting all the commits on my topic branch and linking them to a work item. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third GUID should be the **commit ID**, it's the full commit ID. You can get it via [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/commits#by-repository-id)

To link a commit to a work item, you can refer to this helpful [article](https://dzone.com/articles/associate-work-items-git), it has the detail steps and code sample for your reference.

Comment: Hi Andy, do you or @starain-MSFT have any ideas on how I might associate all the commits on a branch with a work item? The article you linked is very helpful but I would like to simply link all commits on my topic branch to a work item, rather than all commits containing a certain string like in the article. My issue is that after selecting my branch, `branch.Commits` contains the commits from my branch and all the commits from the parent branch. How can I select only the commits from the branch? I can make a separate question with more detail if this comment is unclear. Thank you

Comment: @user95227 I think this thread will be helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805335/get-commits-of-an-item-in-one-branch-with-tfs-rest-api